# Push notifications not received on Android 12 and above.rest of all devices working.Compiledversion and TargetedVersion is 32. Any solution?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-12

Push notifications not received on Android 12 and above.rest of all devices working.Compiledversion and TargetedVersion is 32. Any solution??

Tried by updating dependencies but still not working. I want solution on it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It seems your question is too broad to tackle. Maybe you can share what steps have you done (sample code) and what specific blocker are you experiencing. You can read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create minimal repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you need to ask Push Notification permission. Same as the other permissions you ask run time.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

Comment: Still Not working.

Comment: Need to Change Compiledversion and TargetedVersion 32 to 33.

Comment: Fixed.Actually we need to ask Push Notification permission. Same as the other permissions you ask run time.

Comment: @VishalP That's great.